# Java unsigned byte[2] to int?

Tags: java, type-conversion, byte

All I need to do is convert an unsigned two byte array to an integer. I know, I know, Java doesn't have unsigned data types, but my numbers are in pretend unsigned bytes.

```
byte[] b = {(byte)0x88, (byte)0xb8}; // aka 35000
int i = (byte)b[0] << 8 | (byte)b[1];
```

Problem is that doesn't convert properly, because it thinks those are signed bytes... How do I convert it back to an int?

Comment: Convert to int and then do the shifting.

Comment: It's not really duplicated. The linked question is about 2 bytes to int not unsigned bytes. You can deduce that you have to also mask the first byte from the first answer, but that's not obvious at all. I don't get how they could have mark this answer as duplicated. Is it checked before accepted ? Can we report this ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are no unsigned numbers in Java, bytes or ints or anything else.  When the bytes are converted to `int` prior to being bitshifted, they are sign-extended, i.e. `0x88` => `0xFFFFFF88`.  You need to mask out what you don't need.

Try this

```
int i = ((b[0] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) | (b[1] & 0x000000ff);
```

and you will get 35000.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
int i = ((b[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (b[1] & 0xFF);
```

or

```
int i = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getChar();
```

or

```
int i = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getShort() & 0xFFFF;
```